# jquery get number from name of function to a var

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible get a number from the name of the function, for example:

```
<nameoffunction><number>
function maxchars250()
```

Get the number 250 to a var.

I'm using phpgrid a jqgrid in my project. I need to validate maxchars because the database. In phpgrid we can only use with parametrer colname and value. e.g.:

```
function maxCharsValidate500(value, colname) {

    if (value.length >= 500)
    {
        return [false, colname + ": tem de ter no máximo 500 caracteres."];
    } else {
        return [true, ""]
    }
}
```

But I have 10,50 and 250 chars, so i want create a function e.g. :

```
 maxChars(colname ,value, numberchars){
        if (value.length >= numberchars)
        {
            return [false, colname + ": tem de ter no máximo 500 caracteres."];
        } else {
            return [true, ""]
        }
}
```

and in my function 20,50,250 and 500, I want someting like that

```
verifieMaxChars20(value, colname){
var numberChars=...;
return maxChars(colname,value,numberChars);
}
```

Comment: No, and you shouldn't need it

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by this?

Comment: We need much more information in order to be able to give any kind of truly useful answer.

Comment: Well, it's possible -> https://jsfiddle.net/pLrbs8nr/, but you still shouldn't

Comment: If you have a function maxchars250, and you want `getNumber(maxchar250)` wouldn't it be easier and shorted to write 250 directly?

Comment: I add more description in the main question

Answer (score 1):

You can get the name of a function with function.**name** and then match the number with a regex.

```
var foo = function maxchars250() {
  // do something
}

var number = foo.name.match(/\d+/)[0];
```

I don't know what you're trying to archive, but it really seams like a bad way to approach it. You shouldn't rely on a functions name.